# Run a .c with my own library

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have 3 files, `banca.c`, `conticorrenti.c` and `banca.h`.

`banca.h` contains the declarations of the functions.

`banca.c` contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
```

and the implementations of the functions.

`conticorrenti.c` contains:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "banca.h"
```

How can I run on my Linux terminal this program?

How can `banca.h` read the implementations of the methods if `banca.h` is not included into it?

Comment: `banca.h` doesn't have to "read" anything.

Comment: Are you just asking how to compile it with `gcc`?

Comment: `banca.h` is not supposed to read the implementation of the functions. Header files are usually there to provide declarations, not definitions (although nothing forbids you from doing so, but it's awkward).

Comment: C is compiled language, unless you have some sort of C interpreter. There fore you have to compile source files into executable. @unwind answer shows you how to do that.

Comment: `banca.c` should `#include "banca.h"` as well - just to make sure the functions match their declaration. Otherwise, weird errors can occur if you modify one and forget to adapt the other.

Answer (score 1):

Inclusion is a pre-processor textual processing step. It just pastest the contents of the header into the C file where the `#include` was.

It does nothing to make the code callable, that's a link-time problem.

You need to link the two C files together, something like:

```
$ gcc -o banca banca.c conticorrenti.c
```

would do that by first compiling both C files, then linking the results into a runnable program.

**UPDATE** Your comment implies that you also use pthreads, then you typically must link that:

```
$ gcc -o banca banca.c conticorrenti.c -lpthread
```

Here, the `-l` is an option to the compiler to include the named library when linking.

Comment: There is something strange if I try to launch this files in the standard way.

A lot of error came out for the pthread function, need I to do something of particular for the pthread.h library ?

Comment: You should replace `gcc` with `gcc -Wall -g` in both commands above to get all warnings and debug info